# error on replace multiple special character python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I want to replace multiple double quotes `""` to one `"`. I do this:

```
mystr = '""a"":""b""'

result = mystr.replace('""','"')
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do that?
The result should be `'"a":"b"'`

Comment: seems to work for me... `mystr.replace('""','"') == '"a":"b"'` is `True`

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Yes. but when I read from file it doesn't work.`replace('"','@')` works but two double quotes doesn't work.

Comment: are the `'` (single-quotes) literal? you want them to appear when you `print(mystr)`?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 No I don't. I use `with open("output.json", encoding="utf8",errors="ignore") as infile:
 for line in infile:` and without `errors="ignore"` I got `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte` and this is a huge file